# How to close shared files on Server 2012?

Tags: windows

I cannot seem to find a way to close/disconnect my shared files on my server on Server 2012 R2.

Usually on Server 2008 R2, I do this by going to "Server Manager -> File Services -> Share and Storage Management". From here on the right hand side, I go to Manage Sessions... and in there I can click "Close All".

I cannot for my life find this within 2012 R2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Computer Management > System Tools > Shared Folders > Open Files.

Comment: Thank you! I am fairly certain this answers my problem. Not sure why they don't have it under the same spot as they did in Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I agree with you. It makes no sense but then again the whole 2012 gui doesn't make a lot of sense to me either.